# xsd restrict children to children of another complexType

Tags: xml, validation, xsd, schema

Is it possible to restrict the children of an complexType to exist in the children of another complexType.

for example

```
<xs:element name="people">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="person" type="personType" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="companies">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="company" type="companyType" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

and now in the companyType I want to have employees which should be restricted to exist in the people element above.

Comment: Usually, it is performed with `ID` / `IDREFS`, to avoid repeting information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well thanks to potame. as kjhughes aksed what I do now, I'll post it here.

well I've created a key for company name and a referrer for person.

```
<xs:key name="CompanyKey"  >
  <xs:selector xpath="./companies/company" />
  <xs:field xpath="name" />
</xs:key>
<xs:keyref name="CompanyKeyRef" refer="CompanyKey">
  <xs:selector xpath="./people/person" />
  <xs:field xpath="@company_name" />
</xs:keyref>
```

I just placed these in my root element in the xsd file.

now it is just like a database. the name of company is a key and the company_name of person is a foreign key. so there is a has many relationship between company and person.